# simple proof confusion composite and prime

Tags: proof-explanation

if m>n>0, is m^2 - n^2 composite?

p is composite if p>1 and there exists positive integers r & s such that p = rs where 1< r < p and 1

m^2 - n^2= (m+n)(m-n)
let m =2 and n =1 
let p = m^2 - n^2
p = 3 or (3)(1)
let r  = (m+n) and s = (m-n)
r satisfies that 1< r < p but s doesn't, so m^2 - n^2 is not composite

let m=4 and n =2
p = 12 or (6)(2)
r satisfies that 1< r < p and s satisfies that 1

i am confused about this, how come there can be 2 possible answers to this question? if i answer yes, im right but also wrong....

Answer (score 1):

For $m>n>0$ , $$m^2-n^2=(m-n)(m+n)$$ is composite unless

- $m-n=1$
- $m+n=2n+1$ is prime

Comment: so this is how i should write the proof to this question?

Comment: Actually, the answer to the question is "no" , so it is not a proof, but the description of the conditions for $m$ and $n$ to get a composite number. As you can see, there are counterexamples.